# showing a image from multiple images of a product using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am new at Node.js and working on an e-commerce project where I have two different models for **product** and **image**.

**product.js** model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const productSchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  userId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

**image.js** model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const imageSchema = new Schema({
  imageUrl: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  productId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Product',
    required: true
  }
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Image', imageSchema);
```

At **Image.js** model, there are several images of a single product
After saving images and products, I want to show a single image of a product among several images.
Here is my **controller**

```
exports.getProducts = (req, res, next) => {
  let imagesArr = [];
  Product.find({ userId: req.user._id })
    .then(products => {
      for (product of products){
        Image.find({productId: product._id})
        .then(images => {
          imagesArr.push(images[0]);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
      }
      console.log("Choosed Images", imagesArr);    
    })
    .then(result => {
      return res.render('admin/products', {
        pageTitle: 'Admin Product',
        path: '/admin/products',
        editing: editMode,
        product: product,
        images:imagesArr,
        hasError: false,
        errorMessage: null,
        validationErrors: []
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      const error = new Error(err);
      error.httpStatusCode = 500;
      return next(error);
    });

};
```

Unfortunately, **imageArr** is getting null. I understood that because of asynchronous is getting null.
Please suggest me how can I implement this. 
**I am new at Nodejs**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this in a much cleaner way rather than callback hell. Try the following controller:

```
exports.getProducts = async (req, res, next) => {
  try{
     let imagesArr = [];
     let products = await Product.find({ userId: req.user._id });

     for (product of products){
       let images = await Image.find({productId: product._id})
       if(images && images.length >0) imagesArr.push(images[0]);
     }


     console.log("Choosed Images", imagesArr); 

     return res.render('admin/products', {
       pageTitle: 'Admin Product',
       path: '/admin/products',
       editing: editMode,
       product: product,
       images: imagesArr,
       hasError: false,
       errorMessage: null,
       validationErrors: []
     });
  }catch(err){
     const error = new Error(err);
     error.httpStatusCode = 500;
     return next(error);
  }
};
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Please suggest some links for await/async, callback, callback hell and event handlers tutorial for node.js

Comment: I am glad that this works for you. You can just google it out and learning from the one which you can understand better. Here is a link that you can start with: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PoRJizFvM7s. Can you please accept this answer?

Comment: Oh, i forgot that. Thanks

Comment: @ShantanuNath You can't upvote the answer but you can [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). There's a green checkmark next to the answer on the left which you tick

Answer (score 1):

Just use aggregation so that it can be done in one query only.
This will save you the time of one query.

```
import { Types } from 'mongoose';

let products = await Product.aggregate([
{
    $match:
        {
            userRef: Types.ObjectId.createFromHexString(id),
        },
},
{
        $lookup:
        {
            from: 'images',
            localField: '_id',
            foreignField: 'productId',
            as: 'images',
        },
},
]);
```